# Why this query work in mysql but not from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Following is my query which I run directly in mysql then it works like a charm but when I use the very same query from php by using prepared statement then it does not. I am confused why is that happening:

```
mysql: update login set password='pass', email='email@here.tv' where email = 'wrong@email.com'
$wadb_login_stmt = $con->prepare("update login set password=?, email=? where email = ?");
    $wadb_login_stmt->bind_param("sss", $pass, $email,$email ); // s means only string input is allowed
    $wadb_login_stmt->execute() ;
```

The query works in php if I use username `where username = ?` in where clause and bind it. Kindly let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing the same `$email` variable on `bind_param` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran just realized my stupid blunder :( . I have to send the old email in hidden form field

Comment: @user3027531: Unrelated to the actual issue: **You should always check the return values**. [This](http://pastebin.com/uiPWdQEY) is how you should structure the statements for easier debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wadb_login_stmt = $con->prepare("update login set password=?, email=? where email = ?");
```

Here, you can do (if you want the same email): 
`$wadb_login_stmt = $con->prepare("update login set password=? where email = ?");`
Why you insert two time email? and if it doesn't work, use `echo $wadb_login_stmt->error;`